# How to solve this integral and have arccos(...) as a result?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, problem-solving

$$\int {\sqrt{\csc^{2}x -1}} \, d(\cos^2x)$$

I need to solve this integral in order to arrive to a solution that looks like $x= \arccos(...)$ 
The main substitution is already done, I don't know how to put this equation in a software so I need a help.

Comment: Did you try Mathematica?

Comment: Using the identity $1+\frac{\cos^2x}{\sin^2x}=\csc^2x$, the integral becomes $\int{\frac{\cos^2x}{1-\cos^2x}\text{d}(\cos^2x)}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\int \sqrt{\csc^{2}x -1} \, d(\cos^2x) &= \int\frac {\cos x} {\sin x}\left( -2\cos x \sin x \right)\, dx\\
&=-\int(1+\cos 2x)\, dx\\
&=-x+\frac12 \sin 2x+c\end{align}$$

is this what you want?

Comment: Yes it is, thanks

Comment: I made an edit, i need a result with arccos...

Answer (score 0):

$$\int \sqrt{\csc^2 x-1}\,d(\cos^2 x)\\
=\int \sqrt{\cot^2 x} \cdot 2\cos x\cdot(-\sin x)\,dx\\
=-\int \frac{\cos x}{\sin x}\cdot 2\cos x\cdot \sin x\,dx\\
=-2\int \cos^2 x\, dx$$

Can you continue from here?